# The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration, Windows 7

Tags: php, windows, apache, phpmyadmin

I'm using apache24 with PHP 7.0.3. When requesting http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ I get this error:

> The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. See our documentation for more information.

My PHP config has nothing about slqi to uncomment.
I've looked at the thousand other solutions, and most are for linux and I don't know how to do it for windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure the `extension=mysqli.dll` isn't commented out into php.ini.

Also make sure that you have the `mysqli.dll` files exist inside the extensions folder of your php installation.

Comment: sec search function was being retarded ill update in a sec

Comment: If the file `php_mysqli.dll` in the `ext` folder exists, add that line to the config `extension=php_mysqli.dll`.

Comment: yeah i thought the search would work. what i did was search for extension= and search manually. if i searched verbatim, nothing would show.

Comment: I was also facing the same problem, when checked php.ini file php_mysqli.dll was already not commented, (what i observed is : WAMP logo tool tip was showing server offline, even-though all service were running) , restarting the system helped me.